# increase height of div on button click, and decrease it when I click same button again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, toggle

I have a div with `height:0px` and I want it to increase height to 300px when I click on a button.

When I click on the button again, I want it to get height of 0px again.

CSS

```
nav{
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0;
}
```

JS

```
    $("#hamburger").click(function(){
            $('nav').stop().animate({ height: 300, opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
        },function(){
            $('nav').stop().animate({ height: 0, opacity: 0 }, 'slow');
    });
```

If I only use:

```
$("#hamburger").click(function(){
        $('nav').stop().animate({ height: 300, opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
});
```

the animation works. as soon as I add the other line, it doesn't. I also tried using the `toggle()` function, but the result was that as soon as I load my page, the second part of the toggle function (which is `height:0, opacity:0`) loaded by itself.

here is a [**link to my website**](http://dev.ux-pm.com)

Any ideas? Thanks

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that i am making my website responsive, and that this js code only concerns the mobile version, so to see the result, you should set your browser width to 480px or less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call both functions at the same time. One function wants to increase the height of the `div`, and the other wants to decrease the height of the `div`.

Try something like this:

```
$("#hamburger").click(function(){
    var maxHeight = 300;

    if(+$('nav').height() < maxHeight) {

        $('nav').stop().animate({ height: 300, opacity: 1 }, 'slow');

    } else if (+$('nav').height() === maxHeight) {

        $('nav').stop().animate({ height: 0, opacity: 0 }, 'slow');

    }
});
```

To make it even shorter, you could do:

```
$("#hamburger").click(function(){
    var maxHeight = 300,
        nav = $('nav');

        nav.stop().animate({ height: +nav.height() < maxHeight ? 300 : 0, opacity: +nav.css('opacity') === 1 ? 0 : 1 }, 'slow');
});
```

By the way,  the random `+` signs typecast any strings into numbers, just in case.